# Is there any linux command to find the memory consumption of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, linux, command

How to find the mysql database current RAM consumption using the linux commands ?

Comment: Tried `top`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ps aux | egrep 'USER|mysql'
```

You should check how ps presents output because it depends on the linux distribution you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1. "top"   to see your mysql process PID and general mysql memory and cpu usage
2. "top -H -p PID" to see details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage